# Color is linked when duplicating object

Tags: objects

When I duplicate an object with Shift+D and then change color it also change the color on the original object. Same if I duplicate with Alt+D.
I use Mac if that would matter. Would be happy for any help here since it is very enoying. /Peter

Answer (score 2):

When you duplicate an object, by default the copy keeps the same material as the original. If you want to create a new material for this copy you need to:

- 2.79: Press <kbd>U</kbd> (*Make Single User*) > *Object & Data & Material*
- 2.8: Header menu > *Object* > *Relations* > *Make Single User* > *Object & Data & Material*.

In the case of a linked duplication (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), go in the *Properties* panel > *Materia*l > On the right of the material name click on the dropdown menu and choose *Material*, this way the meshes of the objects are still linked but not their material.

Comment: Also, this default behaviour can be changed in preferences. *Edit->Preferences->Editing->Duplicate data*. One can select which data get copied and which get duplicated.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: I press u but nothing happens. But the last part seem to work.

Comment: If you're using 2.8, U won't work, you need to go in the header menu

Answer (score 1):

Go into the materials tab and you will see, next to the title of the material, something that says "Number of users."

If you click that it will make a single user copy so the materials are no longer linked.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work.